# Start an installed Debian Package from Konsole

Tags: debian, dpkg, konsole

i have installed teamviewer from dpkg and when i list it:

```
    dpkg-query -l
```

it shows up, but how can i run it? Its not under "Applications"

thanks!

Comment: you should have a look at [this answer on how to list the contents of a package](http://superuser.com/questions/82923/how-to-list-files-of-a-debian-package-without-install). You might find there the files provided by the package, and therefore the executables.

Comment: just run `teamviewer` in konsole.

Answer (score 0):

In case `dpkg` indicates missing dependencies, complete the installation by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You can just run `teamviewer` on terminal to start it.